# Не могу понять что с кодом Почему пишет ошибку ? Не могу понять

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Почему пишет ошибку?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZi3A.png) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята заранее спасибо

Comment: кто "пишет ошибку"? Не загружен скрипт `owlCarousel`.

Comment: не прикладывайте код картинкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не подключили файлы CSS & JS файлы.

**CSS**:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel.css">`.
И не забудьте подключить jQuery
`<script src="jquery.js"></script> <script src="owl.carousel.js"></script>`

[Тут](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html) все подробно